# How to connect to postgresql using Docker?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect to the database, but every time I get an error that I could not connect to the database.

Docker ps -a looks like this:

```
ea68340fce5c   postgres:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Exited (1) 2 minutes ago                                       java-postgres
7bcdd7519678   springshop-app    "java -jar app.jar"      2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes               0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   java-app
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: 'java-postgres'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=9567'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=shop_db'

  app:
    build: ./
    container_name: 'java-app'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

I tried to write port '5432:5432', but every time they give an error that the port is busy. Another port also tried, for example 5050:5432.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:19

ADD build/libs/*.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Logs:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

2023-04-03T08:35:55.811Z  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
2023-04-03T08:35:55.812Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The connection attempt failed.
2023-04-03T08:35:56.034Z  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]

Comment: From what you provided, your java app can't connect to your postgresql container, which is dead (exited) ... First step would be to get the postgresql container up and running. If you get errors that ports are used, check which ports are active on your host.

Comment: Yes, indeed I got the following errors:LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-04-03 09:13:04.057 UTC [1] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "0.0.0.0": Address already in use
2023-04-03 09:13:04.057 UTC [1] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
Could you tell me what this is related to? Why does this port work during normal program startup?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any local postgresql installed that uses the 5432 port?

Comment: Well, only pgadmin itself and the database is active in it? Can it affect?

Comment: Maybe try deleting all docker containers and start over?

Comment: @GChuf Every time I delete all the containers and all the images